# How to solve "Service has gone away" error and Page not found in Drupal 8?

Tags: mysql, drupal, mamp, drupal-8

I was building my first Drupal site.  After creating some stuff such as views, blocks, etc... at some point this warnings and errors happened.  I been trying to google every warning and error and no luck yet.  I also checked the "Report Logs" and the only thing I see is `Page not found`, it shows the same errors and warnings for every page only when I click on `Flush all cache`.

Pleasee help..

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => webprofiler [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => Unable to store the profiler information. [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 4 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => http://localhost:8888/drupal-8.1.2/user/1 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => http://localhost:8888/drupal-8.1.2/user/1 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => ::1 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1468798629 ) in Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog->log() (line 79 of core/modules/dblog/src/Logger/DbLog.php).
>
> Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog->log(4, 'Unable to store the profiler
>   information.', Array) (Line: 136)
>   Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel->log(4, 'Unable to store the profiler
>   information.', Array) (Line: 81)
>   Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel->warning('Unable to store the
>   profiler information.', Array) (Line: 120)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler->saveProfile(Object)
>   (Line: 158)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener->onKernelTerminate(Object,
>   'kernel.terminate', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
>   'kernel.terminate', Object) (Line: 61)
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(Object,
>   'kernel.terminate', Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.terminate',
>   Object) (Line: 132)
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.terminate',
>   Object) (Line: 79)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminate(Object, Object)
>   (Line: 32) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->terminate(Object, Object) (Line:
>   606) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->terminate(Object, Object) (Line: 22)

**Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.**

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: CREATE TABLE
>   {cache_default} ( `cid` VARCHAR(255) BINARY CHARACTER SET ascii
>   COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key:
>   Unique cache ID.', `data` LONGBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'A
>   collection of data to cache.', `expire` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT
>   'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or -1
>   for never.', `created` DECIMAL(14, 3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A
>   timestamp with millisecond precision indicating when the cache entry
>   was created.', `serialized` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A
>   flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
>   `tags` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Space-separated list of
>   cache tags for this entry.', `checksum` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET
>   ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The tag invalidation
>   checksum when this entry was saved.', PRIMARY KEY (`cid`), INDEX
>   `expire` (`expire`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
>   COMMENT 'Storage for the cache API.'; Array ( ) in
>   Drupal\webprofiler\Cache\CacheBackendWrapper->set() (line 105 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-8.1.2/modules/devel/webprofiler/src/Cache/CacheBackendWrapper.php).
>
> Drupal\webprofiler\Cache\CacheBackendWrapper->set('theme_registry:storage:mytheme',
>   Array, -1, Array) (Line: 198) Drupal\bootstrap\Utility\Storage->save()
>   (Line: 978)
>   _drupal_shutdown_function()

Comment: Do you see these errors on all pages, or only in front end?

Comment: All pages, everywhere where i flush the cache.

Comment: And what is your server environment? :) Maybe this will help: http://minorpoint.blogspot.com/2007/09/mysql-server-has-gone-away.html

Comment: I was looking for that file :/ and i couldn't find it.im using MAMP and not XAMP

Comment: As a general hint, try to increase the query limit by setting the server's `max_allowed_packet variable` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: Also take a look there: https://www.drupal.org/node/1014172#comment-6538522

Comment: The issue is that i  cannot find 'max_allowed_packet ' anywhere.  In fact, i created my on my.conf file coz according to some posts mamp doesn't has this file. :/ but it didn't work